# Функция добавления в двусвязный список

Tags: c, указатели, списки

При добавлении номера сохраняется какой-то мусор, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
struct List
{
char name[11];
char surname[21];
char number[13];
bool flag;
List*prev;
List*next;
};
List*begin=NULL;
List*end=NULL;

List* check(List*tmp)
{
char number[13];
printf("Enter the name,please\n");
scanf("%11s",tmp->name);
while(strlen(tmp->name)>11)
{
    printf("\nYou type incorrect name");
    scanf("%11s",tmp->name);
}
printf("\nEnter the surname,please\n");
scanf("%21s",tmp->surname);
while(strlen(tmp->surname)>21)
{
    printf("\nYou type incorrect surname\n");
    scanf("%21s",tmp->surname);
}
printf("\nEnter the phone number,please\n");
bool ok;

do
{

    scanf("%13s",number);

ok=true;

for(int j=0;j<strlen(number);++j)
{


    if(isdigit(number[j])==0)
    {
        printf("Don't type number like this!vvedite nomer! \n");

        ok=false;

    }
}

}while(strlen(number)>12 || ok==false);
for(List*tmp=begin;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
{
    if(strcmp(number,tmp->number)!=0)
    {
        strcpy(tmp->number,number);

    }
    else
    {

    printf("Takoyi nomer est' \n");
        break;
    }

}
return tmp;
 }
void add()
{
List*tmp=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
if(tmp==0)
{
printf("Not good!\n");
exit(1);
}
if(begin==NULL && end==NULL)
{
    tmp=check(tmp);
    if(tmp!=false)
    {

    tmp->flag=true;
    printf("\nYour register succesfully added\n");

    tmp->next=0;
    tmp->prev=0;
    begin=end=tmp;
    }

    }
if(end==0)
{
    tmp=check(tmp);
    if(tmp!=false)
    {

    tmp->flag=true;
    printf("\nYour register succesfully added\n");
    tmp->prev=end;
    tmp->next=0;
    end->next=tmp;
    end=tmp;

}
}

}
void show()
{

for(List*tmp=begin;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
{
    if(tmp->flag==true)
    {

            printf("Name:%11s",tmp->name);

            printf("\nSurname:%21s",tmp->surname);

            printf("\nNumber:%13s",tmp->number);
            printf("\n");
        }
        }
        }
  int main()
 {
add();
show();

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала в функции `add()` добавьте скобку `}` после `exit` (и соответственно скорректируйте остальной код), а потом будем смотреть дальше.

В целом же, идея использовать глобальные переменные порочна, попробуйте переписать так, чтобы вся связь между функциями проходила через передачу параметров и возврат результата.

Comment: А в чем может быть проблема, если при добавлении номера он сохраняется каким-то мусором?

Comment: @Ksu, покажите **входные данные** (что вводите), **вывод** (то, что видите с каким-то мусором) и  *весь* код вместе с main  (отредактируйте вопрос, а то такое впечатление, что я вижу один код, а Вы запускаете уже другой).

Comment: а тут можно отправлять картинки, я бы скинула скрин программы?

Comment: Не знаю, никогда этим  не занимался. Посмотрите в справке, или спросите на Мете.

Comment: http://www.foto-me.ru/v.php?id=d2b89a8be31facb4d207f859e54f4266  тут скрин того, что я ввожу и, что выводится

Comment: Суть ошибки в том, что Вы **не копируете** введенный `number[]` в `tmp->number`. / Кроме того, у Вас явная ошибка с логикой в цикле `for` в функции `check()`. / По сути, в цикле нужно только проверять, а копировать вне цикла в случае если повтор не обнаружен.

Comment: Копировать нужно вне цикла for?

Comment: Естественно. Более того, зачем функция `check` возвращает указатель на переданную ей структуру? Наиболее естественным решением было бы окончательное чтение в ней правильных данных и возврат булевого значения false, если ввода данных больше нет (тогда add() возвращает его в main и этап ввода данных заканчивается).  Вы хотите хранить как правильные, так и неправильные данные, так пусть `tmp->flag` и устанавливается внутри `check()`. / Конечно, вернее было бы разбить check на пару функций, скажем `get_struct()` (вводит данные нужного размера в \*tmp) и собственно `check()` (проверяет).

Comment: я переделала так, вынесла копирование за цикл, но ошибка не      пропала 
     for(List*tmp=begin;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
     {
     if(strcmp(number,tmp->number)!=0)
     {
   cop=true;
   
          }
        else
        {
  
   printf("Takoyi nomer est' \n");
  break;
      }
      }
      if(cop==true)
      strcpy(tmp->number,number);

Answer (score 0):

C чего вы взяли, что она не вызывается?
Быть может, вы не там поставили закрывающую фигурную скобку?

```
if(tmp==0)  
{  
    printf("Not good!\n");  
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: когда я запускаю проект, все, что отображается на экране, это сообщение от system("pause")

Comment: а что еще должно показываться на экране, если ни одно из условий не выполнено?

Comment: Я нашла ошибку, я действительно не там фигурную скобку поставила